# Printer printing only one blank page Ricoh SP 111

Tags: printing, linux-mint

Hello all I am using Linux Mint 19.2 based on Ubuntu 18.04. I have two printers:

1. Ricoh SP111 laser printer
2. HP Deskjet 1510 scanner come printer ( I use this only as a scanner)

Detail of the problem:

Whenever I install HP Deskjet 1510 along with Ricoh SP111. The Ricoh SP111 start giving only 1 blank page irrespective of the number of pages. If I remove HP Deskjet 1510 and run `sudo apt-get update` and then update the software. The Ricoh SP111 start giving all the prints okay.

Earlier workaround:

I have posted the problem earlier [Dual Printer Problem Mint 19.2](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1781230#p1781230)

1. At that time I removed the latest version of `HPLIP` (HPLIP-3.20.2) and installed HPLIP-3.17.2 from software channel (Synaptic). It did not work. Hence I removed HPLIP-3.17.10 and installed HPLIP-3.20.2 again. I run `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing` and updated all the software through update manager. This time Ricoh SP111 start giving all the prints okay. The HP Deskjet 1510 also scanning as well through `xsane`. But during the usual new software installations and updates, I don't know when and how it happened again Ricoh SP111 giving 1 blank page.
2. I also observed that during this problem too the Ricoh SP111 giving print sent from `firefox` though it does not print more than 3 pages. All prints sent from any other application fails.

I am using [this](https://github.com/madlynx/ricoh-sp100) driver for Ricoh SP111

Please Help.

Comment: (1) Did you post [this](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=314976) and mark it as solved? (2) Try [Foomatic](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/openprinting/database/foomatic) instead of HPLIP, (3) Try to set the Ricoh to print PXL.

Comment: Yes at that time it solved itself this way. Now I am nt able to find any solution.

Comment: Did you try the other points above?

Comment: Foomatic link taking me to https://openprinting.org and there in list driver status for HP Deskjet 1510 is just paperweight and PXL is looks like for color printer mine is just black & white.Shall I try driver less printing. I m sorry if I feel weird. I am also suffering from insomnia

Comment: I noted one thing when I open http://localhost:631/printers/ in firefox and send test-page to Ricoh SP 111 it still pass a blank page. But when I open a *.pdf, *.jpg file in firefox and send print command to Ricoh SP 111. It prints Okay. It looks that firefox bypass CUPS interface i.e. firefox sends prints on its own and do not use CUPS.

Comment: @harrymc  on https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSDriverlessPrinting#gtk page it says "The print dialog of GTK applications such as firefox and evince does not function in the same way as the Qt and Libreoffice dialogs." that may be the reason that firefox enable to print but not other application. But I have no idea how to set it up for other apps. please help

Comment: I'm just guessing, but you are using an old driver. Try maybe [Ricoh_Aficio_SP1XX_CUPS_driver](https://github.com/alysogorov/Ricoh_Aficio_SP1XX_CUPS_driver). If it doesn't help, try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/764963/963426), note well the comment about the package `ricoh-sp-series`.

Comment: Actually I used this method https://askubuntu.com/questions/641405/ricoh-sp111-printer-setup-help/764963#764963. That's why i was able to print earlier.

Comment: I also submitted this issue there https://github.com/madlynx/ricoh-sp100/issues/77

Answer (score -1, accepted):

AH Now it is working again. I share here how. It was some unknown problem related to `imagemagick`

I decided to search apt history of packages I installed and removed during last time I faced this problem. So following were the terminal commands I found to run after which I was able to print:

```
apt-get install --assume-yes imagemagick*
```

It does following changes:

> **Install:** imagemagick:amd64 (8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6.8),
> imagemagick-6.q16:amd64 (8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6.8)
> **Remove:** graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat:amd64 (1.3.28-2ubuntu0.1)

Then I ran following:

```
apt-get install --assume-yes graphicsmagick*
```

It does following changes:

> **Install:** graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat:amd64 (1.3.28-2ubuntu0.1)
> **Remove:** imagemagick:amd64 (8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6.8),
> imagemagick-6.q16:amd64 (8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6.8)

So this time I ran following command:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick-6.q16
```

and boom I am able to print again from LibreOffice, Adobe reader etc. But it is true I have NO idea why it happened. Thank You for your valuable time.

Comment: Hi, `sudo apt-get install --assume-yes WHATEVER*` is not the best practice I can imagine... (you are a new contributor I try to be *nice* :-) ). No really **`sudo` + `*` is not a good practice**  until you know **exactly** what you are doing, down to the last detail. In the specific with `apt-get ` and `--assume-yes` it is even more dangerous. Fact is that with `*` after a string you may select packages in conflict, `apt` can manage the dependencies but with `--assume-yes` you do not have a fine control on the conflicts, and usually you do not notice has you should.

Comment: Probably they (RICOH driver programmers) did not compile properly the dependencies list and with an `apt` command with `*` and `--assume-yes` you selected a configuration that was not tested or even conceived by them... As a thumb rule doublecheck when you disinstall packages in conflict...`:-)`.

Comment: See last time it worked after imagemagick-6.q16 removed and graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat:amd64 installed. This time it did not worked with graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat:amd64 installation but after installation of imagemagick-6.q16.

Comment: So you see, it seems the drivers need  `imagemagick-6.q16` to work properly. At least in the current version. It could be useful to others if you were able to [edit] your answer and make more clear for the reader, adding when it was working, which action you did, when it stops working, what you did again to make it work... (add some version too, it can be version related). Ps> nice work.

Comment: okay I shall edit my answer and add more detailed facts. It was only thing that at a moment it hits to my mind that there should be a apt history like thing and I should look into it to find solution to problem.( I had no idea that apt records installed and removed softwares, though I saw it in Ubuntu software center )

Answer (score 2):

My Ricoh SP111 printer was also printing blank pages. This worked for me: `sudo apt-get install imagemagick-6.q16`. Thanks.

Those looking to install the printer can download the drivers from here: https://github.com/droidzone/ricoh-sp100

https://askubuntu.com/questions/641405/ricoh-sp111-printer-setup-help
*This resource is very helpful for installation but not exactly accurate.*